# I reach the Google Apps Script time limit of 6 min. How can I improve the script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

As a beginner, I have written a script which is populating all my Google Drive folders into a Google Sheet. Even if the script works, I am running into the `error: Exceeded maximum execution time`, while the result list of my folders is not completed yet.

I am not able to figure out how to handle/fix the Execution Timeout. I was searching already multiple sources and haven't found something which helps me to speed up the script.

My expectation is that script will execute super fast and that the whole list of "maybe" thousands of folders will be populated within max. 1 minute.

##### GAS script

```js
function generateFolderList() {
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  var newSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName);
  newSheet.getRange("A1:N1").setValues([["structure_level", "parent_folder", "folder_name", "folder_description", "folder_id", "folder_url", "owner_email", "sharing_access", "sharing_permissions", "mime_type", "starred_status", "trashed_status", "date_created", "last_updated"]]);
  listFolders(rootFolder, "", newSheet, 1);
}

function listFolders(folder, parentName, sheet, level) {
  var folderName = folder.getName();
  var description = folder.getDescription();
  var folderId = folder.getId();
  var url = folder.getUrl();
  var owner = folder.getOwner().getEmail();
  var sharingAccess = folder.getSharingAccess();
  var sharingPermission = folder.getSharingPermission();
  var mimeType = "folder";
  var starred = folder.isStarred();
  var trashed = folder.isTrashed();
  var dateCreated = folder.getDateCreated();
  var lastUpdated = folder.getLastUpdated();
  
  var rowData = [level, parentName, folderName, description, folderId, url, owner, sharingAccess, sharingPermission, mimeType, starred, trashed, dateCreated, lastUpdated];
  sheet.appendRow(rowData);
  
  var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
  level++;
  while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = subFolders.next();
    listFolders(subFolder, folderName, sheet, level);
  }
}
```

The Google Sheet including the Apps script is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pco1MWwA0RQvSADZeZqkDE6hYJhqOVYyLVScJEdIhO0/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Search continuationToken

Answer (score 0):

Your app script writes to the Spreadsheet for each occurance of a folder or subfolder.  Instead you should collect the information in an array and then write the entire array to Spreadsheet.  Try this, although some of your cell values are objects not strings so at first it won't work until you decide what property of those objects you want to capture.  I just did `toString()`.

```
function generateFolderList() {
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  var newSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName);
  // notice I create an array named folders and pass to listFolders instead of newsSheetthe 
  let folders = [["structure_level", "parent_folder", "folder_name", "folder_description", "folder_id", "folder_url", "owner_email", "sharing_access", "sharing_permissions", "mime_type", "starred_status", "trashed_status", "date_created", "last_updated"]];
  listFolders(rootFolder, "", folders, 1);
  // when its done copy to spreadsheet
  newSheet.getRange(1,1,folders.length,folders[0].length.setValues(folders);
}

function listFolders(folder, parentName, folders, level) {
  var folderName = folder.getName();
  var description = folder.getDescription();
  var folderId = folder.getId();
  var url = folder.getUrl();
  var owner = folder.getOwner().getEmail();
  var sharingAccess = folder.getSharingAccess().toString();
  var sharingPermission = folder.getSharingPermission().toString();
  var mimeType = "folder";
  var starred = folder.isStarred();
  var trashed = folder.isTrashed();
  var dateCreated = folder.getDateCreated();
  var lastUpdated = folder.getLastUpdated();
  
  folders.push([level, parentName, folderName, description, folderId, url, owner, sharingAccess, sharingPermission, mimeType, starred, trashed, dateCreated, lastUpdated]);
  
  var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
  level++;
  while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = subFolders.next();
    listFolders(subFolder, folderName, folders, level);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)